# Bind variable * not declared while creating an explicit cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tried to display values using an explicit cursor but it shows the following error.

> SQL> @C:\Users\91800\Desktop\explicit.sql;
> SP2-0552: Bind variable "C_CUST" not declared.

Here's the code:

```
Declare
c_id customer.id %type;
c_name customer.name %type;
c_add customer.address %type;
cursor c_cust IS select id , name , address from customers;
begin
open c_cust;
loop
    fetch c_cust into c_id , c_name , c_add;
    exit when: c_cust %not found;
    dbms_output.put_line(c_id||' '||c_name||' '||c_add);
end loop;
close c_cust;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the colon after `EXIT WHEN` (and a few other minor things).

See inline comments:

```sql
Declare
  c_id   customer.id %type;
  c_name customer.name %type;
  c_add  customer.address %type;
  cursor c_cust IS select id , name , address from customer; -- CUSTOMER not CUSTOMERS
begin
  open c_cust;
  loop
    fetch c_cust into c_id , c_name , c_add;
    exit when c_cust%notfound;                               -- Remove colon and spaces
    dbms_output.put_line(c_id||' '||c_name||' '||c_add);
  end loop;
  close c_cust;
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9d58b80a23889bce92adad4305018de)*